# How to get data from other apps in ours?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a away to get data from other apps like, google contacts, calendar,etc in our app.
E.g The way google synchronizes with their apps.

Comment: Sometimes this is possible, it depends on the other App how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can access data from other apps using Content Providers. You can learn more about that from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers).

You can either build an ecosystem by creating multiple apps that communicate with each other via content providers, or you can access data from existing apps if they provide content providers.

You can learn how to access the calendar by reading the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider).

So the main takeaway is that you should read about Content providers and also checkout some related tutorials.